# Mono Library is not updated

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin

Thank you for reading my question.

I am updating a third-party library. My goal is to add a new control.
I seem to have added a new class to the namespace containing the group of controls, which I am trying to extend.

However, when I try to link again my "now extended" library, I don't see my new control.

Where does Xamarin Studio get the information regarding the classes contained inside a resource DLL? Is it from an mdb file?
Also, when I compile my library, DLL is created fine and mdb is not created. Is this OK?
Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: Did you recompile the third-party library? If you did not, then it is likely you simply added a class with the given namespace to your project, and your project is then compiled to a separate assembly (either a `dll` or an `exe`).

Comment: Obviously, I recompiled the library.
I did not understand the thing about the separate assembly. My "main" project is a simple exe, which I am trying to link against "my" library and cannot do this since the new class[es] are not visible to Xamarin Studio.

Comment: If you have recompiled the library, then the likely issue is that the actually referenced library is not the one you think is referenced. The metadata about classes that are present in a library is embedded, meaning that there is rarely a way for an IDE to be mistaken on that front.

Comment: How can I check which library is in fact referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I could not figure out how to find out from Xamarin Studio where is each/in-question listed library located on the disk, edit references menu has an option to specify the location from which the newly referenced assembly is loaded. This worked.
Thanks.